# RE-creating a 2D double array from a byte[] array stored in SQL

Tags: c#, arrays, t-sql, multidimensional-array, double

I have a number of very large matrices (sometimes of doubles, but perhaps other types) that can be of varying dimensions. I would like to store an entire array as varbinary(max)

I am able to store the record just fine (I think).  However, when I come to read the data, I can create a new double array with multiple dimensions.  I can read the stored data back from SQL (I think). What I can't figure out now is the inverse of the Buffer.BlockCopy() operation that I employed.

The SQL table looks like this:

```
create table test_varbinary_table(
    id int not null IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,
    name varchar(256) not null,
    rows int not null,
    cols int not null,
    vb_data varbinary(max) null
)
```

The stored procedure to write the data is here:
  (Removed because maybe it's just confusing the issue)
The C# to write a sample record is here: 
  (Removed because I think this part works and I don't know that it helps to solve the problem)

The GetData Stored procedure is this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData] 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * from test_varbinary_table
END
```

I read the table with

```
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdrMatrix = null;
            DataTable tblMatrix = new DataTable();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetData", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                rdrMatrix = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                tblMatrix.Load(rdrMatrix);
                String strResult = "";
                foreach (DataRow dr in tblMatrix.Rows)
                {
                    int r = 2, c = 3;
                    double[,] dary = new double[r, c];
                    byte[] retData = new byte[6 * sizeof(double)];
                    String retName;
                    retName = dr["name"].ToString();
                    strResult += retName + "\r\n";
                    retData = (byte[])dr["vb_data"];  // potential problem?
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(retData, 0, dary, 0, dary.Length); // potential problem?

                    for (int ri = 0; ri< 2; ri++)
                    {
                        strResult += "     ";
                        for (int ci = 0; ci<3; ci++)
                        {
                            strResult += " " + dary[ri,ci] ;
                        }
                        strResult += "\r\n";
                    }

                    strResult +=  "\r\n" ;
                }
                textBox1.Text = strResult;
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        //textBox1.Text = "No Failure!";
    }
```

For the write code, I just manually modified the contents to write a few different records.  When I check the table in SSMS, I can see that it has successfully added rows.  While I cannot read the byte stream, it does change if I change the data and it remains the same if I do not change the data.  However, when I run the c# code to read the records, I get the same result every time ... zeros.

Output looks like:

```
foo
0 0 0
0 0 0
bar
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

So somehow it is either not reading the @data field, or it is not converting it to byte[] properly or the blockcopy is not working correctly. (I think.)  In any case, it's returning zeros instead of the data I stored.

Comment: was is the raw values of `retData`?

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: I found a solution.  I'm still playing with it.  I'll write something up in a few days if I remember.  I could not get Buffer.BlockCopy to unencode, even though that's what I used to encode to a byte array.  Instead I use BlockCopy for encode and tmpArray[i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(retData, i * 8); for decode where double tmpArray[r*c].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using BlockCopy to encode the matrix as a byte array that I could write to a varbinary.  When reading, I used BitConverter to decode from byte array to a double[,].  I don't know why I couldn't get the BlockCopy to work in the other direction.  I missing something.

In any case, my solution so far uses a little different code, but these are the essential elements:

The table where I store the matrix:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_varbinary_table](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [version] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [notes] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [rows] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cols] [int] NOT NULL,
    [checksum] [float] NULL,
    [vb_data] [varbinary](max) NULL
)
```

The method to encode a double[,] into a byte array which will be written directly to a varbinary:

```
public byte[] DoubleMatrixToByteArray(double[,] doubleArray)
{
    int rows = doubleArray.GetLength(0);
    int cols = doubleArray.GetLength(1);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[rows * cols * sizeof(double)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(doubleArray, 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    return byteArray;
}
```

The method to decode from varbinary back into a 2D double array:

```
    public double[,] VarBinaryToDoubleMatrix (byte[] byteArray, int rows, int cols)
    {
        double[,] doubleArray = new double[rows, cols];
        for (int r=0; r<rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<cols; c++)
            {
                doubleArray[r,c] = BitConverter.ToDouble(byteArray, r * cols * sizeof(double) + c * sizeof(double));
            }
        }
        return doubleArray;
    }
```

Checksum:

```
// Summation of all cells in a matrix, just a quick verification check.
// The intent is to verify that when a matrix is read from the database,
// the reconstructed matrix has the same checksum as the one that was saved.
//
    public double computeChecksum(double[,] dblArray)
    {
        int rank = dblArray.Rank; // rank is the number of dimensions of an array.
        int rows = dblArray.GetLength(0);
        int cols = dblArray.GetLength(1);
        double sum = 0.0;

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {
                sum += dblArray[r, c];
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

I save the array with a checksum which I read along with the varbinary field.  I then recompute the checksum and compare it to the saved checksum value.

Comment: It seems to me this is should be a library call to a single function.